# Problema a capturar datos dict(zip en python

Tags: python-3.x, lista, diccionarios, porcentaje

Hola estoy teniendo algunos problemas para capturar datos de un dict zippeado, estoy realizando un detector de imágenes con contenido explicito (NFSW), para una clasificación básica y poder catalogar imágenes y luego entrenar una red que sea mas precisa, para eso utilizo esta base [nsfw_model](https://github.com/GantMan/nsfw_model)

Al pasarle el directorio me devuelve un dict zipeado:

```
{'D:\\datasets\\nsfw_basic _net\\IMG_Pruebas\\0cwopoeme77z.gif': {'drawings': 0.9927581548690796, 'hentai': 0.00583774084225297, 'neutral': 0.0013897231547161937, 'porn': 4.082265149918385e-06, 'sexy': 1.0255172128381673e-05}, 'D:\\datasets\\nsfw_basic _net\\IMG_Pruebas\\0cY8gKK.gif': {'drawings': 6.651235707977321e-06, 'hentai': 0.004124496132135391, 'neutral': 2.9270773666212335e-05, 'porn': 0.9952599406242371, 'sexy': 0.0005795386387035251}, 'D:\\datasets\\nsfw_basic _net\\IMG_Pruebas\\0cz8G2m.jpg': {'drawings': 5.633567501384107e-10, 'hentai': 1.4380176480699447e-06, 'neutral': 3.615332389017567e-07, 'porn': 0.9988616704940796, 'sexy': 0.0011365496320649981}, 'D:\\datasets\\nsfw_basic _net\\IMG_Pruebas\\0d0yYP4.jpg': {'drawings': 6.012066296534613e-05, 'hentai': 0.0035506326239556074, 'neutral': 0.10358280688524246, 'porn': 0.2037489265203476, 'sexy': 0.689057469367981}, 'D:\\datasets\\nsfw_basic _net\\IMG_Pruebas\\0d34y57hboaz.jpg': {'drawings': 9.117220542975701e-06, 'hentai': 0.0001212710194522515, 'neutral': 0.0002957636897917837, 'porn': 0.003615829162299633, 'sexy': 0.9959580302238464}, 'D:\\datasets\\nsfw_basic _net\\IMG_Pruebas\\0e3yPz1.png': {'drawings': 0.0028239593375474215, 'hentai': 0.9935247898101807, 'neutral': 1.656822132645175e-05, 'porn': 0.0035416025202721357, 'sexy': 9.30601527215913e-05}}
```

al intentar extraer como variable la imagen, la categoría y la accuracy/precisión, me devuelve el error de que el segundo dict no es itinerable
nsfw_basico.py

```
import os
import shutil

from nsfw_detector import predict
## cargamos el modelo
model = predict.load_model('./models/mobilenet_v2_140_224/saved_model.h5')

## prediccion enviando modelo y directorio
prediccion = predict.classify(model, './IMG_Pruebas')
print(prediccion)

### Probando modificaciones
print("Probando")
for valores in prediccion.values():
    print("Itinerar sobre valores", valores)
    # for i, k in valores:
    #     print(k)

for key, value in prediccion.items():
    print("Key:", key)
    print("Value:", value)
######

## Movemos la imagen al directorio correspondiente
# Directorio_fuente = './IMG_Pruebas'
# Categoria = './IMG_Pruebas/Probadas'

# for g in prediccion.items():
#     shutil.move(g, Categoria)
```

itinerando sobre values()

```
Itinerar sobre valores {'drawings': 0.9927581548690796, 'hentai': 0.00583774084225297, 'neutral': 0.0013897231547161937, 'porn': 4.082265149918385e-06, 'sexy': 1.0255172128381673e-05}
Itinerar sobre valores {'drawings': 6.651235707977321e-06, 'hentai': 0.004124496132135391, 'neutral': 2.9270773666212335e-05, 'porn': 0.9952599406242371, 'sexy': 0.0005795386387035251}
```

y sobre items()

```
Key: D:\datasets\nsfw_basic _net\IMG_Pruebas\0cwopoeme77z.gif
Value: {'drawings': 0.9927581548690796, 'hentai': 0.00583774084225297, 'neutral': 0.0013897231547161937, 'porn': 4.082265149918385e-06, 'sexy': 1.0255172128381673e-05}
```

también he probado a modificar el predict.py original para que me devuelva solo lo que necesito, pasando variables entre funciones pero si logralo

```
def classify(model, input_paths, image_dim=IMAGE_DIM):
    """ Classify given a model, input paths (could be single string), and image dimensionality...."""
    images, image_paths = load_images(input_paths, (image_dim, image_dim))
    probs = classify_nd(model, images)
    return dict(zip(image_paths, probs))


def classify_nd(model, nd_images):
    """ Classify given a model, image array (numpy)...."""

    model_preds = model.predict(nd_images)
    #preds = np.argsort(model_preds, axis = 1).tolist()
    categories = ['drawings', 'hentai', 'neutral', 'porn', 'sexy']

    probs = []
    for i, single_preds in enumerate(model_preds):
        single_probs = {}
        for j, pred in enumerate(single_preds):
            single_probs[categories[j]] = float(pred)
########## Modificacion
            if pred > 0.96:
               print(j, categories[j], "prediccion mayor 96%", pred)
##########
        probs.append(single_probs)
    return probs
```

En la modificación cree una variable para que retornara junto con probs para utilizarla en el main pero cuando no superar la precisión luego se descuadraba el dict

```
0 drawings prediccion mayor 96% 0.99275815
3 porn prediccion mayor 96% 0.99525994
3 porn prediccion mayor 96% 0.9988617
4 sexy prediccion mayor 96% 0.99595803
1 hentai prediccion mayor 96% 0.9935248
```

Son 5 prediciones y 6 imagenes, probando y probando, con get, max, desempaquetando el dict *d, etc
sigo sin dar con la tecla,

Busco la manera de sacar el valor máximo de precisión de cada imagen y la categoría, si el valor es superior a 0.96 en una categoría, mueve la imagen al directorio de esa categoría, si es menor, lo mueve a otra ej: Triaje, donde se revisaran, a ver si alguien me puede orientar sobre como extraer esos datos del dict, muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El diccionario `prediccion` tiene este formato:

```
{
    key1 : {data1, data2, ...}, 
    key2 : {data1, data2, ...},
    ...
}
```

Entonces cuando haces `for valores in prediccion.values():`, la variable `valores` tendrá un diccionario por cada iteración del `for`.
Para poder iterar ese diccionario, tienes que usar `dict.items()`, entonces para que funcione ese ciclo junto con la parte que tienes comentada, debe ser:

```py
for valores in prediccion.values():
    print("Itinerar sobre valores", valores)
    for k, v in valores.items():
        print(k)
```

---

Ahora bien, si vas a analizar y mover imágenes de un lado a otro, debes incluir la imagen origen, por lo que se debe recorrer ese diccionario de otra forma.
Hay un par de consideraciones adicionales:

**1-** ¿Una imagen puede cumplir varias categorías a la vez?. Si es así, sugiero usar una lista o diccionario de prioridad de criterios.
**2-** ¿Qué pasa si ningún criterio tiene accuracy mayor a 0.96?

En el siguiente código agregué un diccionario `cat_prioridad`, el cual servirá para categorizar la imagen priorizando ese orden. Si ninguna es mayor a `0.96`, por ejemplo `0d0yYP4.jpg`, entonces se moverá al directorio default.
Si prefieres no mover la imagen que no cumpla ninguna categoría, entonces elimina la parte `or (categ == 'default')` del `if`.

```py
cat_prioridad = {'porn':'D:\\Dir01', 'hentai':'D:\\Dir02', 'sexy':'D:\\Dir03', 
'drawings':'D:\\Dir04', 'neutral':'D:\\Dir05', 'default':'D:\\Dir_default'}

for img_src, valores in prediccion.items():
    for categ, dir_dst in cat_prioridad.items():
        if ((categ in valores) and (valores[categ] > 0.96)) or (categ == 'default'):
            img_name = os.path.basename(img_src) # Nombre de la imagen
            img_dst = os.path.join(dir_dst, img_name) # Ruta de destino
            print(f"Moviendo {img_name} --> {dir_dst} --- [{categ}]")
            shutil.move(img_src, img_dst) # <-- Aqui se mueve
            break
```

Con el diccionario suministrado, se produce la siguiente salida:

```
Moviendo 0cwopoeme77z.gif --> D:\Dir04 --- [drawings]
Moviendo 0cY8gKK.gif --> D:\Dir01 --- [porn]
Moviendo 0cz8G2m.jpg --> D:\Dir01 --- [porn]
Moviendo 0d0yYP4.jpg --> D:\Dir_default --- [default]
Moviendo 0d34y57hboaz.jpg --> D:\Dir03 --- [sexy]
Moviendo 0e3yPz1.png --> D:\Dir02 --- [hentai]
```

Comment: Genial, es justo lo que necesitaba, aunque estuve intentando itinerar sobre ítems, pero no conseguí sacar los datos, muchas gracias compañero,